# Trying to Find String in Array of Arrays Based on Index of Corresponding Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, return

I've got an array of names:

```
names = [name1, name2, name3...]
```

that corresponds to an array of arrays that contain quotes which correspond to the array of names.

```
quotes = [[q#1a, q#2b..], [q#1c, q#2d..], [q#1e, q#2f]]
```

I'm trying to create a function where you can enter a specific quote (ex. `q#1c`) and console.log will return the name of the person that said it.

I'm stuck and keep getting undefined. Any suggestions? Below is what I have so far.

```
function findQuote(quote) {
  return quote == `"q#1c"`;
}

let whoSaidIt = (c) => {
  let quote = quotes.index;
  return `${name[c]} said ${quotes[c]}.`;
};

console.log(whoSaidIt(quotes.findIndex(findQuote)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
let quotes = [['q#1a', 'q#2b'], ['q#1c', 'q#2d'], ['q#1e', 'q#2f']];
let whoSaidIt = (c) => quotes.reduce((a, v, i) => quotes[i].includes(c) ? `${names[i]} said ${c}.` : a, '') || 'No-one said that!';

whoSaidIt('q#1c'); //Returns 'name2'
```

Assuming names.length === quotes.length and names[I] said quotes[I], you can use reduce to get your answer. a is '' by default, which is determined by the second attribute.

We simply set the return message when we find the quote. i can be used on names to get the person who said the quote. If no match is found, we can leave a default message using ||.

You may want to consider using an object to store both names and quotes as it may be easier to refer to. { 'q#1a': 'name1', ... }

Answer (score 0):

If the quotes are what you want to look up, then maybe storing them in nested arrays makes this unnecessarily complicated.
I would store the quotes in a flat array and map them to the names.
Maybe something like this:

```js
var names = ["Einstein","Trump","Pikachu"];
var quotes = ["E=mcc","Sad.","Pika!","Two things are stupid."];
var quotees = [0,1,2,0];

function whoSaidIt(q) {
  return names[quotees[quotes.indexOf(q)]];
}

document.getElementById("out").innerHTML=whoSaidIt("E=mcc");
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: That might work but I have to keep the arrays nested for this purpose. Perhaps I can concat the arrays in the body somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your `findQuote` function still needs to look into an array (since `quotes` is an array *of arrays*), which you can do with `includes`. Also, it will be more practical if you pass it the quote to search for instead of hard-coding it in the function. Then you can bind that argument to `findQuote` when using it in `findIndex`:

```js
var names = ['John', 'Helen', 'Anna'];
var quotes = [['q#1a', 'q#2b'], ['q#1c', 'q#2d'], ['q#1e', 'q#2f']];

function findQuote(quote, quotes) {
  return quotes.includes(quote);
}

let whoSaidIt = (c) => {
  return names[c];
};

let quote = "q#1c";
console.log(`${whoSaidIt(quotes.findIndex(findQuote.bind(null,quote)))} said ${quote}`);
```

In a shorter way:

```js
const names = ['John', 'Helen', 'Anna'],
      quotes = [['q#1a', 'q#2b'], ['q#1c', 'q#2d'], ['q#1e', 'q#2f']],
      findQuote = (quote, quotes) => quotes.includes(quote),
      whoSaidIt = c => names[c],
      quote = "q#1c";

console.log(`${whoSaidIt(quotes.findIndex(findQuote.bind(null,quote)))} said ${quote}`);
```

And if you can change your data structure, then it is better to put things together that belong together:

```js
const quotes = [
         { name: 'John', quotes: ['q#1a', 'q#2b'] },
         { name: 'Helen', quotes: ['q#1c', 'q#2d'] },
         { name: 'Anna', quotes: ['q#1e', 'q#2f'] }
      ],
      findQuote = (quote, quotes) => quotes.quotes.includes(quote),
      quote = "q#1c";

console.log(`${quotes.find(findQuote.bind(null,quote)).name} said ${quote}`);
```

Comment: the example you gave for the shorter way works for the most part but it's sending back all of the quotes said by that person instead of just the one that I'm searching for. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: From your question's code, I assumed that was what you were looking for. Of course, this code just takes the data from the data structure, which contains the list of quotes for the person. If you don't want that, then just don't let the function return it, since you already know the quote you are looking for and just can print it yourself after the name.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your `findQuote` function should return another function. You pass in the quote to `findQuote`, and *that* returns the function that `findIndex` calls on each element of the array:

```
function findQuote(quote) {
  return function (el) {
    return el === quote;
  }
}
```

You can then complete the code:

```
let names = ['Bob', 'Dave', 'Mavis'];
let quotes = ['q#1c','q#2c','q#3c'];

let whoSaidIt = (names, quotes, quote) => {
  const index = quotes.findIndex(findQuote(quote));
  return `${names[index]} said ${quote}`;
};

const quote = 'q#1c';
const result = whoSaidIt(names, quotes, quote);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/43opkw7o/1/)**

Comment: Thank you, Andy. I appreciate you editing the question to make it more readable as well.